# How do I POST data with cURL?

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I apologize that there may be a problem with my phone because I use translation.

I want to post xml to ebay systems but this is the error I got

```
Error; ServerUnsupported content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded1
```

```
<?php

        $username = 'user';
        $password = 'user123';
        $xml_data = '<prod:deleteProduct>'.
          ' <apiKey>apikey1234</apiKey>'.
          ' <sign>rzdx7etHb3afTmtVQeyKPGjgzaSenb8987456465498</sign>'.
        '   <time>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'</time>'.
          ' <productIdList>'.
          '    <item>539087067</item>'.
        '   </productIdList>'.
        '   <itemIdList>'.
        '   </itemIdList>'.
        '   <lang>tr</lang>'.
        '</prod:deleteProduct>';


          $ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://dev.gittigidiyor.com:8443/listingapi/ws/IndividualProductService?wsdl');
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml_data);
          $resul = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch); 

          echo $resul;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you sending XML data so the **Content-Type** should be **text/xml**

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: Just change **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** to **text/xml**